# click blank area go back to selected section

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<li class="list "><a href="javascript:">A</a>

    <ul class="names">
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list "><a href="javascript:">B</a>

    <ul class="names selected">
        <li class="list selected"><a href="javascript:">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list "><a href="javascript:">C</a>

    <ul class="names">
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="list"><a href="javascript:">4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

    $('.list').click(function () {
        var that = this;
        $('.list').each(function () {
            if (that == this) return true; //continue
            $('.names:not(:hidden)', this).slideToggle();
        });
        $('ul.names', this).slideToggle();
    })
ul.names{display: none;}
li.list{
    width:150px;
       background:#A9FF7A;
}
ul.names {
    width:150px;
    background:#A9FF7A;
}
ul.selected{
    display: block;
}
li.selected{
    background:red;
}
```

online Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gyYyd/

**B**'s submenu **1** is highlighted. If I click on menu A or C, then A or C section will be opened, but how do I click PAGE BLANK area (outside of the background color) to go back to B section (to open B section)

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by PAGE BLANK?

Comment: What's PAGE BLANK area?

Comment: outside of the ul and li. sorry wasnt clear. outside of the background color as I put background color on them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture `click`s on the `document` object and trigger a `click` on the required list item.

```
$(document).click(function() {
    var selected = $('.selected:first');
    if(!selected.closest('ul.names').is(':visible')) {
        selected.closest('.list').trigger('click');
    }
});
```

Also, make sure to `return false` from your current list item `click` handler - so that normal clicks on list items don't propagate to the above handler.

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/gyYyd/2/

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but the second click, makes the B menu closed? any way to keep it open even 2nd time clicked? means if it opened keep it as open status